# How to send request http delete using loopj at android

Tags: android, http-delete, loopj

I make some android app.
To log out, I must send http delete request to server.
I used loopj liberary.

So, I make like this.

**ConnectionInfo.java**

```
public ConnectionInfo(Context ctx) {    
    this.context = ctx;    
}

public void sign_out(String Url, AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler) {
    CommonClient.setCookieStore(myApplication.getCookieStore());
    CommonClient.delete(context, Url.toString(), handler);
}

public void sign_in(HashMap<String, String> params, JsonHttpResponseHandler handler) {
    Uri.Builder requestUri = new Uri.Builder();
    requestUri.scheme(SCHEME);
    requestUri.authority(HOST);
    requestUri.path(sign_in);
    CommonClient.post(context, requestUri.toString(), params, handler);
}
```

**CommonClient.java**

```
public class CommonClient {
    private static final AsyncHttpClient AsyncClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void post(Context mContext, String actionserver,
    RequestParams params, JsonHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    AsyncClient.post(mContext, actionserver, params, responseHandler);
}
```

and then

Some Activity class, call sign_in method.

```
connectionInfo.sign_in(params, UserLoginJsonHandler);
```

and Finished some work, the other Activity class call sign_out method. Like this.

```
connectionInfo.sign_out(url, asyncHttpResponseHandler);
```

But, I login another ID.
Keeping login before user.

I think, different login and logout session or cookies something?

How Can I logout using loopj?
How do I Fix it?

Please help me.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am already make delete method. 
But not work. 
In fact, the method work very well.
server return 204 to me.
But keep alive login status.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [delete](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.java#L826) method on the `AsyncHttpClient` it is also overloaded so you can choose the one that fits your need. here is a sample usage :

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
AsyncClient.delete(context, url, responseHandler);
```

Comment: Oh sorry. I am already make delete method. 
But not work. 
In fact, the method work very well.
server return 204 to me.
But keep alive login status.